# Is it possible to call a PHP file from within a stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am working on a private PHP project to teach myself new stuff. One of the things I am learning with the project are MySQL stored procedures. I have a working news module, which does not yet support automatic RSS-Feed generation.

While programming that part, I was wondering if you can execute a PHP file from within a stored procedure. The reasoning is that I would not need to worry about when to update the XML-File, kind of like a `TIMESTAMP` field with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

So, can you execute a script from within a stored procedure?

Comment: One thing you NEVER EVER want to do is spider calls like this.  Even if you could do that... why would you want your PHP server to call your Database Server which can call your PHP server which could call your database server etc...  By doing this, your opening the door to some of the most fantastic spaghetti code you have ever seen.  I have dealt with a program once that used SQL Server that made a command line call to a java program to create a report which then called the database again to get the report data and make the HTML to display the report... it was BAAAAAAAAAD!!

Comment: @Zoidberg Well, I tentatively added the functionality to php functions because it was the more secure way. After reading your comment, I think I'm going to leave it that way.

Comment: Awesome, just didn't want you to run in to the same problems I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't do that.

MySQL doesn't know how to handle PHP scripts.

Comment: Nor does it support HTTP requests.